# GitHub Dekstop with Webhook to Go Live?

Tags: github

Can I use GitHub Desktop (OSX) to commit changes to my repo, and have those changes go live via the app and a Webhook that I set up on my server?

I see that SSH is required on the server to do this, but I am unfamiliar with the command line and would like to know if the Desktop application for GitHub can also do this too?

Answer (score 1):

From [GitHub Desktop - Making changes in a branch](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/making-changes-in-a-branch/):

> GitHub Desktop tracks all changes to all files as you edit them. You can decide how to group the changes to create meaningful commits.

So, answer for first part of the question is yes.

For ssh... you need to check [**this**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ssh.htm) stuff out. It's normal to use SSH protocol.

Comment: So just that I understand correctly, will I need to learn the command line? Or will the GitHub Desktop app for El Capitan take care of all this setup for me?